# Can't get my listbox to display objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

Hello everyone I've been trying to put some objects in an ASP.NET list box but it's just not working.

I do have an overridden ToString method so I can't understand why this statement won't work.
Here's the code that I use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fitnessClassList.Count(); i++)
{
    lbDisplayItems.Items.Add(fClassList.getFClass(i));
}
```

And the errors that I get:

```
Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 
                    'FitClassManage' to 
                    'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem'    

Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 
                    'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection.Add(System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem)' 
                    has some invalid arguments
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASP.NET [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.aspx) is not like the WinForms [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx). You cannot add any object to him. Its item collection ([ListItemCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.aspx)) is limited to [ListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx) (so you can't add your business objects relying on `ToString()` for visualization).

Use this code:

```
ListItem listItem = new ListItem(fitnessClassList.getFitnessClass(i).ToString());
lbDisplayItems.Items.Add(listItem);
```

Do not forget that if you'll use that `ListItem` you won't have the object but its display name (the result of `ToString()`). See the link about the `ListItem` for more details.

As alternative you may set the [DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.datasource.aspx) of the [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.aspx) to your `fitnessClassList` (if it supports that in any way, see this [overview on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a4kyhcx.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to display a "custom" item in a list box. I got it to work doing the following:

- I created a usercontrol that had the controls I wanted named MyListItem. In my case I wanted a checkbox and textfield.
- I created a new myListBox that inherited from ListBox and created an Add method. This method did the following:
- It had one string argument for text to be displayed
- It created an instance of MyListItem and assigned the text string to its Text property.
- I assigned an event handler to respond to the checkBox check event.
- I added my custom item to the myListBox.controlls.

When I programatically added items to myListBox, my custom items were displayed!!

Answer (score 0):

Method Add expects ListItem object (or string, see links below), but you are passing a custom class.

You probably want following:

```
lbDisplayItems.Items.Add(new ListItem(fitnessClassList.getFitnessClass(i).ToString()));
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.aspx - there are only 2 "Add" methods.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx for available constructors.

Comment: It shouldnt be so because my fitnessClassList has fitnesClass objects in it and Im trying to pass them.I thought that the ToString is going to be displayed in the ListBox for each one of the objects

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the .DataSource and .DataBind properties on the listbox.

```
lbDisplayItems.DataSource = fitnessClassList;
lbDisplayItems.DataBind();
```

Check out this link for a small example
http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-to-databind-listbox-using-stack.html

Comment: You're welcome. I saw your reply below that you're new to Asp.Net. I'd suggest you research the datasource/databind pattern, as almost all the Asp.Net data controls use that pattern. It will come in handy as you build more controls. Good luck